# Increasing number on button click till X, then start over again

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I have to do button that starts from zero and if you click it, it increases by one. After 3 it start over from zero.

Here is the code I wrote

html:

```
<button id='counter-button'>0</button>
```

Dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
  button.onClick.listen(increase);
}

increase(e){
  var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
  var value = int.parse(button.text);
  while(true){
    value = value + 1;
    button.text = '$value';
    if(value == 4){
      value = 0;
    }
    continue;
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I think I should use while loop but something ain't right.

Comment: You should not use any loop to solve this problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forget that the main function calls the increase function every time the button is clicked. I got it working, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may go as simple as that:

```js
const incrementTo3 = ({target}) => {
  const currentCounter = +target.textContent
  target.textContent = (currentCounter+1)%4
}
```

```html
<button onclick=incrementTo3(event)>0</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary while loop:

```
increase(e){
  var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
  var value = int.parse(button.text);
  value = value + 1;
  if (value == 4)
    value = 0;
  button.text = '$value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
increase(e){
  var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
  var value = int.parse(button.text);
  if (value  < 3){
 button.text = value ++;
return;
}
button.text = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What output are you getting at the moment?

I'm not super familiar with Dart-specific functions, but follow the logic below and it should work:

```
increase(e){

      //1. grab button object
      var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
    
      //2. grab value, check it's actually an integer by logging it 
      var value = int.parse(button.text);
    
      //3. if it's already 3, make it zero, otherwise increment
      value = (value == 3) ? 0 : (value + 1); 
    
      //4. set value back in
      button.text = '$value';
    }
```

On step three above, it's basically another way of writing this:

```
if (value == 3){
    value = 0;
} else {
    value++; //or value = (value + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
increase(e){
  var button = querySelector('#counter-button');
  var value = int.parse(button.text);
  value == 4 ? value = 0 : value+1;
  button.text = '$value';
}
```

Comment: The mistake you are actually doing is appending the value to the button before checking it is 3. If you can check and then append the value to the button it will solve your issue.